# Are there problems in NP that would solve P vs NP, but are not NP complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, p-vs-np

NP-complete problems are the "hardest problems" in NP. This means that all other problems in NP reduce (in polytime) to these problems. A consequence of this is *if* we were to find some polynomial time algorithm to solve one of these problems, we could prove $P = NP$. And if we could prove that no polynomial time algorithm could exist, this implies $P \neq NP$.

Are there other problems in $NP$ that have this property? That is,

Is it possible for a problem $X$ in $NP$ to not be NP-complete, but we could still solve $P$ vs. $NP$ by determining if it has polynomial time lower bounds.

Of course, proving that there is an exponential lower bound on any NP problem proves $P \neq NP$, but are there problems in NP where finding a polynomial time lower bound (besides NP complete problems) shows $P = NP$?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\mathsf P \neq \mathsf{NP}$ in your last sentence?

Comment: @Watercrystal I'm asking for something more along the lines of a class of problems that act like NP-complete problems, where if you find a polynomial time solution to them, you can prove $P = NP$. If you show exponential lower bounds on problems in this class, then $P \neq NP$, yes. But that is true for any problem in $NP$. I think my comment makes sense, please let me know if I am not being clear. Thanks.

Comment: I think this analogy might be clearer actually: If one found a solution to graph isomorphism, that would not prove $P$ = $NP$. But if one were to find a solution to SAT, that would prove $P$ = $NP$. Is there a problem that is not NP-complete that has this same property of proving $P = NP$?

Comment: If $GI \notin P$, then $P \neq NP$.

Comment: @PålGD yes, but I’m asking for problems that satisfy the inverse. A problem $X$, such that $X \in P$ then $P = NP$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Ladner's theorem shows that for any problem $X \in \mathrm{NP} \setminus \mathrm{P}$ there is a problem $Y \in \mathrm{NP} \setminus \mathrm{P}$ such that $Y$ is reducible to $X$ but not vice versa.

If we apply the construction from Ladner's theorem to e.g. $\mathrm{SAT}$ we obtain a problem $Z \in \mathrm{NP}$ such that either $Z$ is neither in $\mathrm{P}$ nor $\mathrm{NP}$-complete (in case that $\mathrm{P} \neq \mathrm{NP}$); or $Z$ is simulatenously in $\mathrm{P}$ and $\mathrm{NP}$-complete (if $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$).

In other words $Z$ is not $\mathrm{NP}$-complete unless for trivial reasons, and proving that $Z$ belongs to $\mathrm{P}$ entails $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer provided by @Arno, the problems sought by the OP are those belonging to the class of NP-intermediate problems: $N P I=N P \backslash(P \cup N P C)$. Despite the interest, we still do not know of any natural problem belonging to this class, all we have are natural candidates, e.g. graph isomorphism, discrete logarithm and factoring. A few years ago I have found, along with my coauthor, another possible candidate which has been useful for the construction of a [cryptographic protocol](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7018923):

**Exponentiating Polynomial Root Problem (EPRP)**

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial with $deg(p) \geq 0$ with coefficients drawn from a finite field $GF(q)$, and $r$ a primitive element for that field. Then, the problem of finding roots of

$p(x) = r^x$

is believed to be NP–intermediate, i.e., it is in the complexity class NP but it is supposed not to be in P nor NP–complete.

This problem is at least as hard as the discrete logarithm, it can be regarded as a generalization of it since the discrete logarithm problem is a particular case of EPRP when $deg(p) = 0$. Additional details can be found [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7018923) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7471).

Comment: But would proving ERP to be polytime lead to the conclusion that $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$?

Answer (score -1):

My original answer below takes "not $\mathsf{NP}$-complete" in the OP's title and text at face value. As far as I can tell it is correct, and not incompatible with Arno's answer, whose interpretation of "not $\mathsf{NP}$-complete" is less "strict" — though probably closer to what the OP wanted and yielding more interesting properties!

---

The answer is no.

Consider a problem $X$ in $\mathsf{NP}$ that is not $\mathsf{NP}$-complete. Suppose that finding out some bound on the complexity of $X$ would show $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.

The thing is that if $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$, then all problems in $\mathsf{NP}$ are $\mathsf{NP}$-complete, except for the two trivial problems “always yes” and “always no”.

So $X$ would have to be either “always yes” or “always no”, whose complexity is well-known (they are constant time) and has no bearing on the  $\mathsf{P}$ vs $\mathsf{NP}$ problem.

Comment: This argument seems to assume that the only way the P vs. NP problem might be resolved, is to show that P = NP. What if finding out some bound on the complexity of X would show that P != NP?

Comment: @kaya3 the OP specifically asked for problems which would imply that P=NP. There are lots of problems for which finding an exponential lower bound would show that P≠NP, as the OP argues.